# ForEach-Object return all objects three times in powershell (Azure VM)

Tags: azure, powershell, foreach, virtual-machine

I have this Powershell line which should list all virtual machines from selected subscription and I have total of 3 subscriptions.

```
$azureSubscriptionID = "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
foreach ($subs in $azureSubscriptionID)
    {
        Write-Output "Collecting VM facts from subscription $subs"

         $vms += Get-AzureRMSubscription | ForEach-Object {Select-AzureRMSubscription $_ | Out-Null; Get-AzureRmVM -WarningAction SilentlyContinue} 
    }
```

Issue is that when running the script and using $vms is that it will list all available vms subscriptions three times in a row like this:

> VM A     VM B     VM C
>   VM A     VM B     VM C
>   VM A     VM B     VM C

What am I doing wrong and how to fix that? or are there alternative ways to get all vms from X subscription in few lines? Using this in Azure runbook.

Comment: your code shows just ONE item in the `foreach ($subs in $azureSubscriptionID)` loop. so i would start by checking the values at each step of your code.

Comment: Ye, I know but in the future there are maybe more than one subscription as parameter and that is why i need loop them.

Comment: thank you for the "why". [*grin*] i see that `AdminOfThings` has shown a solution - good to know you have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to cycle through all of your subscriptions and list all of the VMs, you can do the following:

```
Get-AzureRMSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $sub = Select-AzureRMSubscription $_
    Write-Output "Collecting VM facts from subscription $($sub.Subscription.Id)"
    Get-AzureRmVM
}
```

The issue with your attempt is you are getting all subscriptions (`Get-AzureRmSubscription`) during each loop iteration regardless of the value(s) contained in `$azureSubscriptionID`. To fix your code, you would need to run `Get-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $subs` or `Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $subs`.

---

If you want to do further processing with the data you have gathered, I would consider some alternative approach for when you explicitly target known subscriptions.

```
$azureSubscriptionIDs = "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx","yyyyy-yyyyy-yyyyy-yyyy","zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzz"
# $vms is an array of custom objects
# each custom object contains a subscription ID and the associated VMs Names
$vms = foreach ($sub in $azureSubscriptionIDs) {
    $null = Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub
    $subvms = Get-AzureRmVM | Select -Expand Name
    $sub | Select @{n='Subscription';e={$_}},@{n='VMs';e={$subvms}}
}
# You can access the subscription ID now with the Subscription property
# You can access the VMs Names with the VMs property
# List all vms under subscription 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx'
$vms | Where Subscription -eq 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx' | Select -Expand VMs
# List all vms for each subscription with a custom console message
foreach ($sub in $vms) {
    Write-Output "Here are all the VMs for subscription $($sub.Subscription)"
    $sub.VMs
}
```